# physical meaning of dimensionless parameter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

What does it mean when there is nor not a dimensionless parameter in my model?
In quantum harmonic oscillator, we don't have dimensionless parameter while in hydrogen atom case we have one which is the fine structure constant. But I don't see their intrinsic differences.

Answer (score 1):

The intrinsic difference is that a dimensionless parameter is invariant if we change our units, whereas other parameters do depend on the units. The former arises when we can specify the property in question in terms of the other measurements made from within the system. The latter kind must refer to physical objects *outside* the system. Thus an angle is the ratio of two lengths within a "circle system" and needs no further qualification  - it is invariant to any transformation that maps circles into circles. In contrast, a full statement of the force my seat thrusts on me to stop me falling towards Earth's center must be made by invoking objects *outside* the system - the mass of a certain lump of iridium in Paris, a number of wavelengths of the light made by a certain standard oscillator and time taken for light to traverse this wavelength-defined length.

When we talk about $\alpha$, we have the same situation as for the angles. The first interpretation of $\alpha$ was as the ratio of the orbital speed of the ground state electron in the Bohr atom to the speed of light and, as such, independent of any system of units.

Comment: Then was is the role played by the dimensionless parameter, for example, in the hydrogen atom case?

Comment: And I didn't understand the examples you gave. It seemed that your examples discussed difference between dimensionless quantity(angle) and dimensional quantity(force)  and did not focus on the dimensionless parameter. So I didn't understand your "the former...the latter..."argument neither.

Comment: @Fan Well its really the same thing. See my updated last sentence